# Customize Split-window-below - C x 2

Tags: window

C-x 2
On `Split-window-below`,

1) i like the cursor/point to be in the other window (newly opened) and not in present window.

2) instead of loading in the current-buffer in the other window, i prefer it to be the previously visited file (or) my first entry in `(switch-buffer)` (or) `C-x b` list

3) Does elisp support hooks for methods (`split-window-below` hook)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have the similar need, but for `C-x 3 (split-window-right)`:

```
(defun chunyang-split-window-right ()
  (interactive)
  (select-window (split-window-right))
  (switch-to-buffer (other-buffer)))
```

Comment: Seems like you beat me to it :)
Can I suggest a small change?
Replace
```
(split-window-right)
(other-window 1)
```
with
```
(select-window (split-window-right))
```

Comment: @bmag Thanks for suggestion. I didn't notice the return value of (split-window-right) and the (select-window) function.